# extracting contents of file as variables in python

Tags: python

I have a file like below in `Linux`.

`file_name` is `batch_file.txt`.

`sub_directory` is `code_base/workflow_1`

`script_name` is `code_base/workflow_1/session_1.py`

`batch_file.txt` contents are:

```
1#1#workflow_1#1#session_1#2023-04-02#FDR#2
1#2#workflow_2#2#session_2#2023-04-02#FDR#2
1#3#workflow_1_2#3#session_2#2023-04-02#FDR#2
```

I want to read the contents of `batch_file.txt` in the `session_1.py` file and create variables based on the `file_name` and `sub_directory`. The variables would be:

```
batch_id = number before 1st #
workflow_id = number between 1st and 2nd #
workflow_name = number between 2nd and 3rd #    
session_id = number between 3rd and 4th #   
session_name = number between 4th and 5th #
run_date = number between 5th and 6th # 
flow_name = number between 6th and 7th #    
flow_id = number after 7th #
```

I have this:

```
batch_content = open('batch_file.txt', 'r')
batch_content.readlines()
```

But I am not sure how to proceed further?

Comment: Look at the `split` method of `str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split to achieve your output

```
with open("batch_details.txt") as search:
    for line in search:
        line = line.rstrip() # remove '\n' at end of line
        if 'workflow_1' and 'session_1' in line:
                batch_id, workflow_id, workflow_name, session_id, session_name, run_date, flow_name, flow_id = line.split('#')

print(batch_id)
print(workflow_id)
print(workflow_name)
print(session_id)
print(session_name)
print(run_date)
print(flow_name)
print(flow_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want variables that are named at runtime, you *can* do that, but shouldn't.

Instead I would use a list of dictionaries.

```
[
  {'batch_id': x[0], 'workflow_id': x[1], 'workflow_name': x[2], 
   'session_name': x[3], 'session_id': x[4], 'run_date': x[5], 
   'flow_name': x[6], 'flow_id': x[7]}
  for line in text.splitlines()
  for x in (line.split('#'),)
]
```

Result:

```
[
  {'batch_id': '1', 'workflow_id': '1', 'workflow_name': 'workflow_1', 'session_name': '1', 'session_id': 'session_1', 'run_date': '2023-04-02', 'flow_name': 'FDR', 'flow_id': '2'}, 
  {'batch_id': '1', 'workflow_id': '2', 'workflow_name': 'workflow_2', 'session_name': '2', 'session_id': 'session_2', 'run_date': '2023-04-02', 'flow_name': 'FDR', 'flow_id': '2'}, 
  {'batch_id': '1', 'workflow_id': '3', 'workflow_name': 'workflow_1_2', 'session_name': '3', 'session_id': 'session_2', 'run_date': '2023-04-02', 'flow_name': 'FDR', 'flow_id': '2'}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `csv` module to read the data into a dictionary (or optionally use pandas to read into a dataframe).

As an example:

```
import csv 

with open('batch_file.txt', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames=['batch_id','workflow_id','workflow_name','session_id','session_name','run_date','flow_name','flow_id'], delimiter='#') 
    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)
```

> 

```
{'batch_id': '1', 'workflow_id': '1', 'workflow_name': 'workflow_1', 'session_id': '1', 'session_name': 'session_1', 'run_date': '2023-04-02', 'flow_name': 'FDR', 'flow_id': '2'}
{'batch_id': '1', 'workflow_id': '2', 'workflow_name': 'workflow_2', 'session_id': '2', 'session_name': 'session_2', 'run_date': '2023-04-02', 'flow_name': 'FDR', 'flow_id': '2'}
{'batch_id': '1', 'workflow_id': '3', 'workflow_name': 'workflow_1_2', 'session_id': '3', 'session_name': 'session_2', 'run_date': '2023-04-02', 'flow_name': 'FDR', 'flow_id': '2'}
```

For each line read from the file, you get a dictionary with your "variable" names as the key and your file contents as the value. With this you can do whatever you wish.

For instance:

```
import csv 

with open('batch_file.txt', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames=['batch_id','workflow_id','workflow_name','session_id','session_name','run_date','flow_name','flow_id'], delimiter='#') 
    for line in csv_reader:
        print(f"The workflow name of workflow id {line['workflow_id']} is {line['workflow_name']}")
```

> 

```
The workflow name of workflow id 1 is workflow_1
The workflow name of workflow id 2 is workflow_2
The workflow name of workflow id 3 is workflow_1_2
```

---

If you are needing to work more with this data or perform any transformation of the data, `pandas` may be more appropriate.

A silly example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('batch_file.txt', header=None, names=['batch_id','workflow_id','workflow_name','session_id','session_name','run_date','flow_name','flow_id'], sep='#')

df['message'] = df.apply(lambda line: f"The workflow name of workflow id {line['workflow_id']} is {line['workflow_name']}", axis=1)

display(df['message'])
```

> 

```
0     The workflow name of workflow id 1 is workflow_1
1     The workflow name of workflow id 2 is workflow_2
2    The workflow name of workflow id 3 is workflow...
```

Comment: the `CSV` method is what I was looking for. But that will print me all the lines in the file. What I want is to print only the line based on the `sub directory` and `script name`. Here I want to print only the first line not all the lines

Comment: @nmf  You can use pathlib and the `__file__` special variable to get the filename and directory of the script that is being executed.  Start with `from pathlib import Path`, then `sub_dir = Path(__file__).parent.stem` == `"workflow_1"` and `scriptname = Path(__file__).stem` == `"session_1"`  or Path().name == `"session_1.py"`